# Static script files for angular 5 stops working with traefik proxy with docker swarm

Tags: angular5, docker-swarm, traefik

I have a nginx container which will serve angular app on port 80 for all domains.
When i start the container in docker swarm as a service and bind it to port 80. The application runs fine.

But I tried to use traefik reverse-proxy and after that only HTML is working and all the scripts is not loading with error

> Refused to execute script from '' because its MIME type
>   ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is
>   enabled. Refused to execute script from 'http://app.local/runtime.js'
>   because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict
>   MIME type checking is enabled. app.local/:1 Refused to execute script
>   from 'http://app.local/polyfills.js' because its MIME type
>   ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is
>   enabled. app.local/:1 Refused to execute script from
>   'http://app.local/styles.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is
>   not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. app.local/:1
>   Refused to execute script from 'http://app.local/vendor.js' because
>   its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type
>   checking is enabled. app.local/:1 Refused to execute script from
>   'http://app.local/main.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not
>   executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

For the traefik i followed the steps from https://jmkhael.io/traefik-as-a-dynamic-reverse-proxy-for-docker-swarm/

```
docker network create --driver=overlay traefik-net 


docker service create \
--name traefik \
--constraint 'node.role==manager' \
--publish 80:80 \
--publish 8080:8080 \
--mount type=bind,source=/var/run/docker.sock,target=/var/run/docker.sock \
--network traefik-net \ traefik \
--docker \
--docker.swarmmode \
--docker.domain=jmkhael.io \
--docker.watch \
--logLevel=DEBUG \
--web
```

and for the app service

```
docker service create \
--name web \
--label 'traefik.port=80' \
--label traefik.frontend.rule="app.local; Path: /" \
--network traefik-net \ app
```

Is this the proper way? Or am i missing any other configurations. 
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What URL is your angular app expecting? it should expect app.local. Take out the `--docker.domain=jmkhael.io` and also the `; Path: /` part of the rule in web service. See if those help.

Comment: Hi Sorry that domain is sample. I gave app.local onle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app started working after removing the

> Path: /

part in the web container label.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, because the same problem exist with `PathPrefixStrip`